# Mysql database to html page

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a database from which I would like to display two columns in a table.

I have the following code however, this does not work and I get

> ```
> "; } mysqli_close($con); as my answer.[solved after removing echo "<br />"]
> ```

Code follows:

```
<html>
<style>
div.transbox
  {
  width:850px;
  height:500px;
  margin:30px 50px;
  background-color:#ffffff;
  border:1px solid black;
  opacity:0.9;
  padding: 20px;
  filter:alpha(opacity=60); /* For IE8 and earlier */
  }



  ul#navigation
  {
  link-style: none;
   padding: 5px 20px 5px 20px
  margin: 0;
  }
  ul#navigation li
  {
  display: inline;
  }
  h1#heading
  {
    color:#ffffff;
        background-color:#000000;
        text-decoration:none;
font-family:georgia, times, serif;
font-size:2em;
padding:10px;
border-bottom:3px solid #ff6600;
  }
  ul#navigation a {
        color:#ffffff;
        background-color:#000000;
        text-decoration:none;
font-family:georgia, times, serif;
font-size:1.126em;
padding:10px;
border-bottom:3px solid #ff6600;}

  div.line
  {
  display: inline;
  }

 ul#navigation a:hover {
        color:#000000;
        background-color:#ff6600;
        padding:10px;
        border-bottom:3px solid #000000;}
  </style>

<head><h1 id="heading">Food Review </h1>
<ul id="navigation">
<li><a href="form4.html">Review</a></li>
<li><a href="Ratings.html">Ratings</a><li>
</ul>
</head>

<body background = img.jpg>
<div class="transbox">
<div class="work">
<?php
define('DB_NAME','form');
define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_PASSWORD','toor');
define('DB_HOST','localhost');
$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);
if(!$link)
{
    die('could not connect : ' . mysql_error());
}
$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$link);
if(!$db_selected)
{
    die('Can\'t use ' .DB_NAME . ': ' .mysql_error());
}
$result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT fname,Ratings from demo1");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo $row['fname']." ".$row['Ratings'];
}
mysqli_close($link);
?>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
}
```

I did the following changes but still no results are displayed.

Comment: The html you have within the `<head>` tag is invalid.  That code belongs in the body.

Comment: Wow that is a seriously malformed HTML document. Why do you have actual display content within the `<head>` element?

Comment: Also mysqli_close($con); seems faulty, i don't see $con being defined anywhere, shouldn't you use $link ?

Comment: I would recommend you to use a framework to better organize your work and your learning guide them. I use CodeIgniter for example.

Comment: not sure this help you but you selected database via mysql_select but other database commands  are mysqli

Answer (score 2):

```
$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);
```

Since you initialized the connection with `$link` you should close `$link`

```
 mysql_close($link);
```

and change the following line

```
echo "<br />";
```

with

```
echo "<br>";
```

and you are mixing `mysql` with `mysqli` please check and use only one which suits you

Comment: Ok i did this and still i get no result

Comment: try to remove the line `echo "<br />";` and check

Comment: i removed it now nothing is displayed

Comment: `$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);   
echo "$num_rows Rows\n"; `  //try to check if records exists

Comment: i do not get a reply but i stored the values in the table

Comment: you are mixing mysql with mysqli please check and use only one which suits you

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure some data from the `demo1` table contains characters that mess with html and breaks the tag nesting.

Try replacing this:

```
echo $row['fname']." ".$row['Ratings'];
```

with

```
echo htmlentities($row['fname']." ".$row['Ratings']);
```

**EDIT**: Also, replace `mysql_connect` with `mysqli_connect` and `mysql_select_db` with `mysqli_select_db`

Comment: i still didnt get anything

Comment: It did work but thanks a lot for the effort sir i really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing mysql functions and mysqli.
Have a look here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php how to use mysqli properly

```
<?php

define('DB_NAME','form');
define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_PASSWORD','toor');
define('DB_HOST','localhost');

$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);

/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT fname,Ratings from demo1");

while($row = $result->fetch_array())
{
$rows[] = $row;
echo $row['fname']." ".$row['Ratings']."<br />";
}

$mysqli->close();
?>
```

There is also a procedural style but I highly recommend the object oriented ;)

EDIT: Also a good idea is to enable error reporting for development. 
Add this to the beginning of your php file:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP install is broken and not functioning, so your PHP code is being sent to the browser, which interprets the `<?php` tag as a broken/unknown HTML tag, and the entire contents of the page are ignored, until you reach

```
echo "<br />";
```

where the `/>` serves as the closing bracket for this "malformed" `<?php` tag.

That's why you only see the mysqli_close business in your browser, because everything else is hidden as a broken tag.